# Finding a DetailsView control (Edit Template) with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, detailsview

I have a details view that contains the following code:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            Approve: <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkApproved" CssClass="btnStatus" /> 
            Reject: <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkReject" CssClass="btnStatus"/>
            Cancel: <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkCancel" CssClass="btnStatus" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Justification">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server"
                                id="txtJustification"
                                TextMode="multiLine"
                                width = "100%"
                                ReadOnly="true"
                                Height="5em"
                            />
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I am trying to run the following jQuery and it is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id$='txtJustification']").hide();
    $("[ID$='chkReject']").click(function () {
         alert("reject");
    });


})
   </script>
```

This code is hiding the textbox, however it is not working when I click the Reject checkbox.  I have also tried the following but with no avail:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id$='txtJustification']").hide();
    $(".btnStatus").click(function () {
         alert("reject");
    });


})
   </script>
```

What seems to be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the script tag in the end of the code.

Comment: Care to explain a little more on that?

Comment: Put the following script tag before </body> tag:
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("[id$='txtJustification']").hide();
    $(".btnStatus").click(function () {
         alert("reject");
    });

   </script>

Comment: don't wrap the code in $(document).ready(function () {} and try it.

Comment: I ran your code and it works very much fine.
Try putting <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> on <head> tag or if u r using masterpage then add it in masterpage's head tag.
Send me your email, i'll send u the code.

Comment: I have all of that in my masterpage already, I know that jQuery is working fine on the page, it just does not seem to be finding the control in the detailsview.

Comment: i've sent you the file in info@evanwatkinswebdesign.com. Please check the attached file.

Comment: Edit: i created a simple table [status] with columns status and justification for my datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon missing in the last

}) this should be });